# Soldering with bus wire on perfboard

Tags: soldering, protoboard

What's the proper way to solder with bus wire on perfboard.

I used perfboard for the first time on a project recently. I designed a great layout and started soldering the components to the copper pads; the joints were perfect and beautiful. Then I realized I still needed to add the connections. So I put the bus wire down and was successful in getting the device working, but it was pretty ugly underneath.

Comment: Consider using strip board instead of just regular perfboard; it connects each pad in the row with a built in strip, and you can use a drill bit through an unoccupied pad (or just a cheap engraving tool) to break the strips where necessary. -- Then you can use bus wire to connect the few stragglers that still need to be connected. -- It's a huge time saver!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

One suggestion I can give is to use the thinnest wire possible, and to cut your wires to the exact length you need to route them around your perfboard.

Another clever technique, which I have not personally tried, is to make a "Wiring Pen" as in [this instructables](http://www.instructables.com/id/Wiring-Pen/)

Answer (score 7):

I put together some "Breadboard Hints" at 
http://lucianifamily.org/getting-it-done/assembly-hints/assembly-hints-index.html#breadboard-hints

Using a combination of clips (Vector T42-1) and pins (Vector K24A)
you can put together some neat perfboards. The hints at the site
list the supplies and show an example breadboard.

Comment: I think you meant to link here:  
http://www.luciani.org/getting-it-done/assembly-hints/assembly-hints-index.html#breadboard-hints

Comment: Yeah. I was lazy and just linked to the top page in my ee-notes section ;)

Comment: I know, its almost 8 years later, but the above links redirect to a "your computer is infected!" page.  A sign of the times :)

Answer (score 2):

I found this page to be a useful starting point on techniques for prototyping with perfboards:
http://elm-chan.org/docs/wire/wiring_e.html

The techniques used are shown in a video as well:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i5MNLTc7YhY

There is also a company selling some tools, although none of these a strickly necessary and they are a bit pricey:
http://www.roadrunnerelectronics.com/

For instance, this Instructable shows how to create a wiring pen:
http://www.instructables.com/id/Wiring-Pen/